# Bootstrap and Jinja - centering images

Tags: django, jinja2, django-bootstrap3

I'm using Bootstrap3 in my Django project and I would like to display images in row next to each other horizontally and I have:

```
<div class="row">
    {% for image in images %}
        {% if image.image %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
                </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

and it works. But images are displayed from left to right (for example, if there is only 1 image, it's pinned to the left and it doesn't look great). How can I center all images to always be centered independent on number of images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To center a list if block in a main block independent of number of child block, you can use** `css flex + justify-content: center` **like this :**

```
<!-- Without bootstrap -->

<style>
    .images-box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
</style>

<div class="row images-box">
{% for image in images %}
    {% if image.image %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
            </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>

<!-- With bootstrap 4 -->

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
{% for image in images %}
    {% if image.image %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image.image.url }}" />
            </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**NB :** With bootstrap *version 4* you have to add class="row d-flex justify-content-center" to the **parent** `div` class. If you are forced to use `V3` then try vanilla css as above.